# Show that $K$ of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-vector-spaces

I read in an article for proof that the part $K$ of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is compact. In this demonstration, the author proceeded to the following steps for the demonstration:

1- He showed that: $K$ is closed for $\tau $.

2- He showed that: On $K $ the topology $\tau $ coincides with a metrisable topology.

3- He showed that: $K$ is sequentially compact.

Therefore, $K$ is compact.
I just think to show $(2)$ and $(3)$. I did not understand why the author showed that $K $ is closed?

An idea please.

Comment: Take $X=[0,1], K=(0,1)$ and see where  the argument fails.

Comment: I did not understand your comment

Comment: @Kavi To show that $ K $ is metrisable it must first be shown that K is closed?

Comment: No. The fact that $K$ so closed is required dot make sure that limits of subsequences belong to $K$.

Comment: Then for show that a subset of topological space is compact : it suffices to show that K is closed, metrisable and sequentially compact?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "compact". In modern definitions, "compact" subsets must be closed. They  are not necessarily metrizable, though. But closed, metrizable, sequentially compact does imply compactness.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $K$ being sequentially compact already means that the limit of the subsequence is in $K$, closedness is superfluous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma My understanding is that 1) was used to prove 3). That is I meant by my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be: $K$ is shown to be closed (probably it has to be anyway, when $X$ is Hausdorff e.g.), and the closedness of $K$ is *used* in the proof that $K$ is sequentially compact (e.g. because the convergent subsequence (of a sequence from $K$) is shown to exist in $X$ at first and then closedness of $K$ inside $X$ implies that the limit lies in $K$, which is necessary for the sequential compactness.

So you're right that 2.+3. would be enough in itself, but I think we might need 1. in the proof of 3. Hard to say for sure without looking at the proof itself, but at least my scenario would make sense.

Comment: What is this K anyway?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet see the original question?

Comment: I don't see any definition of K in the Q.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet there is no definition because the OP asked in a general way. It’s the subspace that has to be proved compact.